# ngRoute does not fire in angularjs controller

Tags: html, angularjs, routes, ngroute, route-provider

I have created a simple application to test ngRoute. I have a main page called index.html with one link to a page called "informationdisplay.html". I have setup the route in the controller of the main page but it doesn't function.

Below is index.html code

```
<html>

 <head>
   <title>Ng route test</title>
       <script    

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> 
       </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
  <h2> Select Location from List</h2>
  <a href="#info">Information</a>      
</body>    
</html>
```

My code in the controller

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp",['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/info', {
        templateUrl: 'informationdisplay.html',
        controller: 'informationController'
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

});

mainApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missed to configure several things.

1. `ng-view` directive should be added `index.html` so that route template will be loaded at that place.
2. `href="#info"` should be `href="#/info"`
3. Change redirectTo to the, `info`

   ```
   <body>
     <h2> Select Location from List</h2>
     <a href="#/info">Information</a>
     <div ng-view></div>
   </body>
   ```